Covariant derivative of a Wilson line
Does the covariant derivative of a Wilson line given by $$W[A; z_0, z] = {\cal P}e^{-i\int^z_{z_0} dz ~A^af_{abc}}$$
vanish, i.e. $$D_zW[A; z_0, z] = 0~?$$

Hi @Dr. user44690, to fix notation, are you following a reference?

@Qmechanic No. Not really

You would need $F=0$ so the Wilson line  is  path independent and only a function of the endpoint $z$.  In that case $\nabla_X U=0$ where $U(z)= P\exp\{i \int^z A_\mu(x) dx^\mu\}\in G$

Does this hold for non-abelian Wilson lines as well? Also, does Wilson lines have a trace somewhere?

I think it true for any Lie group. A Wilson line with a trace is a Wilson loop. It does not have any free ends.

Then how will you multiply two wilson lines if the trace already is taken?

For a fixed gauge field, Wilson loops are just numbers, so they multiply just like $2\times 2=4$. Without the trace they are matrices in your chosen representation of the gauge group, and given a common end point  $y$, they mutiply as such: $W(x,y)W(y,z)= W(x,z)$.


Let us write the Wilson-line of a simple open curve $\gamma: [s_i,s_f]\to \mathbb{R}^4$ as
$$ U(s_f,s_i)
~=~ \mathcal{P}\exp \left[ i\int_{\gamma} A_{\mu}~ dx^{\mu} \right].\tag{1} $$

The path-ordering $\mathcal{P}$ becomes important if the gauge potential
$$A_{\mu}~=~A^a_{\mu} T_a\tag{2}$$
is non-abelian. Here $T_a$ are the generators of the corresponding Lie algebra.

The Wilson-line has groupoid properties, e.g.,
$$U(s_3,s_2)U(s_2,s_1)~=~ U(s_3,s_1), \qquad  U(s,s) ~=~ {\bf 1}.\tag{3}$$

If one differentiates wrt. the final point $s_f$, one gets
$$\frac {dU(s_f,s_i)}{ds_f} 
~=~  i\dot{\gamma}^{\mu}(s_f)~A_{\mu}(\gamma(s_f)) ~U(s_f,s_i). \tag{4}$$

Now let us return to OP's question. Eq. (4) can be written as
$$  D_{\dot{\gamma}(s_f)}U(s_f,s_i)~=~0,\tag{5}$$
if we introduce the gauge covariant derivative as
$$ D_{\mu}~=~\partial_{\mu}-iA_{\mu}. \tag{6}$$

For more information, see e.g. this & this related Phys.SE posts.



Does the $U$ have a trace or not? For non-abelian case?

No trace assumed.

So there are implicit group indicies $i, j$ for every $U$?

$\uparrow$ Yes.

Any references you can provide which I can follow up in this regard?
